# Generate Password according to rows in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am working with a windows form application using c#. This program is able to read the data from the sql server and then and export to excel. I got this part working. However, I want to be able to generate a list of random password in a column according to how many rows of item I have in my excel. Let say my password column is column 'M' (password) and let say if the excel file has ten items (10 rows), then column 'M' will display 10 random generated password. If there is 5 item, then column 'M' will display 5 random password. I am thinking to use for loop to do this. But I have not idea where to start. Help will be appreciated. I am using Microsoft.interop.excel library 15.

Here is the password pattern that I want

```
abcd001
abcd002
abcd003
abcd004
abcd005
```

In the excel let say if I have 10 rows, then 10 column M it will display a list of password

```
   A    B    C    ..... M 
1                    abcd001
2                    abcd002
3                    abcd003
4                    abcd004
5                    abcd005
6                    abcd006 
7                    abcd007
8                    abcd008
9                    abcd009
10                   abcd010
```

Here is the part of my code to create excel file

```
private void exportToExcel(){
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlApp.Visible = false;
    Excel.Workbook xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(missing);
    Excel.Worksheet xlEmployeeDetail= xlwb.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;

    xlEmployeeDetail.Name = "Employee Detail"; 
     xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 1] = "Employee Id";
    xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 2] = "First Name";
    xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 3] = "Last Name";
    xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 4] = "Nick Name";
    xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 5] = "Email";
    xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 6] = "Entry Year";
    xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 7] = "Leave Year";
    .........
    xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 12] = "User Login ID";
    xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[1, 13] = "Password";

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        i++;

        int e_id = dr.GetInt32(1);
        string f_Name = dr.GetString(5);
        string l_Name = dr.GetString(6);
        string n_Name = dr.GetString(7);
        string e_email = dr.GetString(8);
        int e_Year = dr.GetInt32(9);
        //int l_Year = dr.GetInt32(10);

        xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[i, 1] = t_id;
        xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[i, 2] = f_Name;
        xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[i, 3] = l_Name;
        xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[i, 4] = zh_Name;
        xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[i, 5] = t_email;
        xlEmployeeDetail.Cells[i, 6] = e_Year;
        .....
    }
    dr.Close();
 }
```

Comment: And what happens with your current code? It's not clear which part of the code is the problem at the moment - is it just random string generation? FWIW, storing a password in an Excel spreadsheet sounds like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: umm, will you suggest I do directly in db?

Comment: Furthermore, constant strings with increasing postfixes as passwords is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm suggesting that we can't tell what the problem is based on your question, and that anything that exposes passwords in plaintext is a bad idea. Basing passwords on a pattern is *definitely* a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a mutual prefix for your password before the `while` loop.

```
string passwordPrefix = "abcd";
```

Then, inside the loop, add the prefix to a properly formatted `i.ToString()` (using `String.Format`). You might want to create the format dynamically, because you might need `000` or `0000` etc., depending on the number of rows.